# cannot import name 'views' from 'superlists'

Tags: django, python-3.x, tdd

I'm working with Harry Percival's book about TDD and I have problem with Sjango. I got:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'views' from 'superlists'
```

It is showing me the the problem is with: `from . import views`

This is my code in my file **urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url   
from django.contrib import admin   
from . import views

urlpatterns = ['',
    url(r'^$',views.home_page, name = 'home'),
]
```

Does somebody know what to do with that problem?

Comment: when i delete from . import vievs i got an error:TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().

Comment: Most likely views.py does not exist or is in the wrong place.

Comment: Please copy and paste the entire traceback when asking questions about errors.

Comment: i think i found a solution here:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rLPDxpXIFc

Comment: it needs from lists.views import home_page

Comment: Note that the `''` at the beginning of your `urlpatterns` list is a mistake, you should remove it. I don't think you really have it in your actual code, otherwise you'd get a different error.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on [this chapter of the book](https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/chapter_unit_test_first_view.html), then the correct import is

```
from lists import views
```

It looks like you are currenly editing the project's urls.py, `superlists/urls.py`. That means that you need `from lists import views`. You could only replace `from lists import views` with `from . import views` if you were editing the lists app's urls, `lists/urls.py`.